# Memory address when function handle called in Python

Tags: python, memory-address

I understand this might not be a programming question, but I still wonder:

Why does Python return the memory of the function when the function handle is called for?

```
>>> my_func
<function my_func at 0x3ead488>
```

When / How is that useful? Why not display the actual contents of the function (while still holding the same functionality; a link to the function)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking at the `repr()` representation of a Python object that doesn't have a literal representation. Such objects follow the default `<type ... at 0xid>` pattern most Python objects follow.

It's purpose is for you to be able to distinguish different `function` objects from one another, even if their names are the same; if you have two `foo` functions you'd want to be able to see if they are the same object or not; the `id()` value in the representation allows you to do so.

Quoting from the [`__repr__` method documenation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__):

> Called by the `repr()` built-in function and by string conversions (reverse quotes) to compute the “official” string representation of an object. If at all possible, this should look like a valid Python expression that could be used to recreate an object with the same value (given an appropriate environment). **If this is not possible, a string of the form <...some useful description...> should be returned.** The return value must be a string object. If a class defines `__repr__()` but not `__str__()`, then `__repr__()` is also used when an “informal” string representation of instances of that class is required.
>
> This is typically used for debugging, so it is important that the representation is information-rich and unambiguous.

The contents of a function are a) potentially much larger, and b) require a source file to be available. The `function` object itself only references *bytecode*, the compiled code object. Even if the source files are available printing a container object full of functions would result in overly verbose output.

If you wanted to see the source code for a given function object, use [`inspect.getsource()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getsource) on the object. This *can* raise an `IOError` exception if no source is available.

Comment: If the function provided docstring and that is what you are after, you can retrieve it with `function.__doc__`, or use the `inspect` module to get even more introspection.

Comment: Also, displaying the source code of a function via simply calling `__str__` on it would kind of make it impossible to write closed-soirce python modules.

Comment: @aruisdante: well, the source would not be available, another reason not to using the source as a representation.

Comment: Right, my comments were adendums to your answer, not saying you did anything wrong :)

Comment: What possible scenario would there be for having two ```foo``` functions? Why wouldn't one overwrite the other?

Comment: @wnnmaw: Sure you can. The **function object** has a `__name__` attribute. You can set it to any string you like. You can import functions from different modules and bind them to new names, but that won't set `__name__`. You can store references to the function objects before definining a new one under the same name, etc.

Comment: @wnnmaw: The name under which you stored a reference to a function and `funcobject.__name__` may start out the same, they don't have to *stay* the same.